# How can I optimise this method?

Tags: actionscript-3, optimization, stage3d, starling-framework

I have been working on creating an assets class that can generate dynamic `TextureAtlas` objects whenever I need them. The specific method is `Assets.generateTextureAtlas()` and I am trying to optimise it as much as possible as I quite frequently need to regenerate texture atlas's and was hoping to get a better time than my 53ms average.

53ms is currently costing me about 3 frames which can add up quickly the more items I need to pack inside my texture atlas and the frequency I need to generate them. So an answer to all the pitfalls within my code would be great.

[The entire class code is available here in a github gist.](https://gist.github.com/a05b932023862abe3091)

The `RectanglePacker` class is simply used to pack rectangles as close together as possible (similar to Texture Packer) and can be found [here](https://github.com/xLite/RectanglePacking/tree/patch-1).

For reference, here is the method:

```
public static function generateTextureAtlas(folder:String):void
{
    if (!_initialised) throw new Error("Assets class not initialised.");

    if (_renderTextureAtlases[folder] != null)
    {
        (_renderTextureAtlases[folder] as TextureAtlas).dispose();
    }

    var i:int;
    var image:Image = new Image(_blankTexture);
    var itemName:String;
    var itemNames:Vector.<String> = Assets.getNames(folder + "/");
    var itemsTexture:RenderTexture;
    var itemTexture:Texture;
    var itemTextures:Vector.<Texture> = Assets.getTextures(folder + "/");
    var noOfRectangles:int;
    var rect:Rectangle;
    var rectanglePacker:RectanglePacker = new RectanglePacker();
    var texture:Texture;

    noOfRectangles = itemTextures.length;

    if (noOfRectangles == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < noOfRectangles; i++)
    {
        rectanglePacker.insertRectangle(Math.round(itemTextures[i].width), Math.round(itemTextures[i].height), i);
    }

    rectanglePacker.packRectangles();

    if (rectanglePacker.rectangleCount != noOfRectangles)
    {
        throw new Error("Only " + rectanglePacker.rectangleCount + " out of " + noOfRectangles + " rectangles packed for folder: " + folder);
    }

    itemsTexture = new RenderTexture(rectanglePacker.width, rectanglePacker.height);

    itemsTexture.drawBundled(function():void
    {
        for (i = 0; i < noOfRectangles; i++)
        {
            itemTexture = itemTextures[rectanglePacker.getRectangleId(i)];
            rect = rectanglePacker.getRectangle(i, rect);

            image.texture = itemTexture;
            image.readjustSize();

            image.x = rect.x + itemTexture.frame.x;
            image.y = rect.y + itemTexture.frame.y;

            itemsTexture.draw(image);
        }
    });

    _renderTextureAtlases[folder] = new TextureAtlas(itemsTexture);

    for (i = 0; i < noOfRectangles; i++)
    {
        itemName = itemNames[rectanglePacker.getRectangleId(i)];
        itemTexture = itemTextures[rectanglePacker.getRectangleId(i)];
        rect = rectanglePacker.getRectangle(i);

        (_renderTextureAtlases[folder] as TextureAtlas).addRegion(itemName, rect, itemTexture.frame);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, when profiling this, what parts is it that takes time?

Comment: It's the entire method, `generateTextureAtlas()`. It takes an average of 53ms to complete and I'm looking for any ways to speed it up. It uses other methods within that method which can be seen inside the Assets class github gist. I've tried optimising as much as I can but I'm still stuck with an unhealthy 53ms execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Well reading the project & finding what all can be optimized would sure take time.

Start by removing multiple calls to `rectanglePacker.getRectangle(i)` inside loops.

For example :

```
    itemName = itemNames[rectanglePacker.getRectangleId(i)];
    itemTexture = itemTextures[rectanglePacker.getRectangleId(i)];
    rect = rectanglePacker.getRectangle(i);
```

perhaps, could have been:

```
    rect = rectanglePacker.getRectangle(i);
    itemName = itemNames[rect];
    itemTexture = itemTextures[rect];
```

If **getRectangle** does indeed just 'get a rectangle' & not set anything.

Comment: Actually the vector indexes have `Id` at the end of the function, I guess you didn't notice. Also lines 102-109 are 0-2ms so they don't really need any attention. Many thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

I think the bigger issue at hand is this, why oh why do you HAVE to do this during run-time, in a situation when this can't take more time? This IS an expansive operation, no matter how much you optimize this you will probably end up with it taking about 40ms or similar when done in AS3.

This is why these kind of operations should be done during compile time or during "loading screens" or other "transitions" when frame-rate is not critical and when you can afford it.

Alternatively create another system in c++ or some other language which can actually handle the number-crunching that gives you the finished result.

Also, when it comes to checking performance, yes the entire function takes 53ms, BUT, where are those milliseconds used? 53ms says nothing and is only the "overhead profiling thing" where you found the culprit, you need to break it down into smaller chunks to gather some reliable information about what it is that ACTUALLY takes time, inside that function.

I mean, inside that function, you have 3 for loops, several calls to other classes, casts, deletes, creations. It's not like you are doing one thing, that function probably results in ~500 lines of code and a bazillion cpu operations. And, you have no idea where it is used. I would guess that it is the `rectanglePacker.packRectangles();` that takes 60% of that time, but without profiling, you and we don't know on what to optimize, we simply don't have sufficient data.

If you HAVE to do this during run-time in AS3, I would recommend doing this spread out during several frames and distributing workload evenly during 10 frames or so. You could also doing it with help of another thread and workers. But most of all, this seems like a design error since this could probably be done at another time. And if not, then in another language which is better at these kind of operations.

The easiest way to profile this is to add a couple of timestamps similar to:

`var timestamps:Array = [];`

And then push `getTimer()` at different places in code, and then print them out when function is done

Comment: I need to render items to an isometric grid in 1 draw call using a QuadBatch. They only allows a single texture to be used so I need to make sure everything I need is in a single texture. Sometimes though I need to add more items, like a new piece of furniture. It isn't happening every frame but any reduction in execution time would be great.

As for the method, the majority of it each plays its own part ranging from 10-30ms.

Comment: I was hoping more for advice on optimisation through simple visualisation. For example I swapped `Math.round(i)` to `int(i + .5)` which is the sort of optimisations I am looking for. Instead of requiring actual profiling results, just point out obvious optimisations that you know will speed up execution in a situation like this. The full class code is available if you need to see the code within the other methods. Many thanks for the reply!

Comment: The code provided is good performance wise, there are hardly anything that you can do to it. However: 1) you declare i:int but you use it as a number int(i + 0.5) this causes conversions. 2) rectanglePacker.getRectangleId(i) is called twice, this can be cached to a local variable. Rule of thumb, always use local variables if you use it more than 1 time. 3) You have a weird inline function `itemsTexture.drawBundled(function():void` depending on when and how this function is invoked this might be very expensive since "everything" in this function scope is available to the anonymous function.

Comment: But in the end, it really doesn't matter. It's more an issue on another scale, this code is allready optimized and you can't improve its' performance "that much". You have to find another solution. Because the code is good performance wise, there are only very minor issues in it. You might gain a couple of MS but you need to get total execution time down to 15ms to avoid sluggishness on your machine. And you can't get that from micro-optimizing this code.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, it's unlikely that the reason of bad performance is non-optimized AS code. Output from the profiler (Scout, for example) wold be very helpful. However, if your purpose is just adding new textures, I can suggest several optimizations:

1. Why would you need to re-generate the whole atlas every time (calling `Assets.getTextures()` and creating new render texture)? Why don't you just add new items to the existing atlas? Creation of a new `RenderTexture` (and, thus, a new texture in GPU memory) is very costly operation, because it requires sync between CPU and GPU. On the other hand, drawing into `RenderTexture` is carried out entirely inside GPU, so it takes much less time.
2. If you place every item on a grid, then you can avoid using `RectanglePacker` as all of your rectangles can have the same dimensions matching the dimensions of a grid.

**Edit:**

To clarify, some time ago I had a similar problem: I had to add new items to the existing atlas on a regular basis. And the performance of this operation was quite acceptable (about 8ms on iPad3 using 1024x1024 dynamic texture). But I used the same `RenderTexture` and the same `Sprite` object that contained my dynamic atlas items. When I need to add a new item, I just create new `Image` with desired texture (stand-alone or from another static atlas), then place it inside the `Sprite` container, and then redraw this container to the `RenderTexture`. Similarly with deletion/modification of an item.

Comment: You may be on to something with re-using the `RenderTexture`, don't know why that slipped my mind. Although the reason I redraw every item is because I need to make sure I can fit as much as possible. Each item can vary in its dimensions greatly so I need to make sure it's getting packed as tightly as possible so as to not waste any space.

Comment: Actually, the reason I create a new `RenderTexture` object *(after just checking)* is because depending on how closely the items are packed, the width and height of the texture is not guaranteed to be the same after every `packRectangles()` call. This is done so I'm not using a full 2048x2048 `RenderTexture` when really I might only need 128x2048 etc etc.

Comment: I understand, but re-using the same larger texture may be more performant than creating new smaller texture each time. Again, if objects in your project are arranged on a grid (and thus have similar dimensions), it may be not so hard to implement packing algorithm that guarantees resulting dimensions. For example, look at this article: [An effective recursive partitioning approach for the packing of identical rectangles in a rectangle](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.69.1352&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: _Each item can vary in its dimensions greatly_ — sorry, I've missed this. Then the problem is more complex. Anyway, I think it's worth a try to re-use a texture.